# Subtle difference between following words:

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary, word-difference

1.Brief, Concise, Succinct

2.Detailed, Thorough, Lengthy

I know #1 are derivatives of short
and #2 are of long

but there is some subtle difference between them

• Brief= short; not containing too many words

• Concise= giving a lot of information clearly, to the point and in few words.

Now a concise thing can be lengthy , however, it'd be still briefer than what it could have been. As all the unnecessary details are omited

• Succinct= briefly and clearly explained but may or may not contain all the main details

• Detailed= Having many details, showing attention to details.
Details are given priority but some of them can be omitted

• Thorough = complete, not even a single detail has to be ruled out

• Lengthy = it can either be detailed or thorough or even long-winded (wordy, having unnecessary details, tedious)

Am I right with my interpretations?

Can't trust the googled definitions since it also lists sentimental as synonym for nostalgic. Lol

Comment: Your alternatives are not "derivatives" - they're just *different words that can **sometimes** overlap in meaning*. And ***brief*** doesn't always mean "not containing too many words", as evidenced by widespread usages such as *a brief visit [to some person / place]* - or even [*wearing a brief dress.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wearing+a+brief+dress%22) But I never heard of even facetious references to a ***concise*** or ***succinct** dress*.

Comment: i know i only meant in written. btw are my definitions right?

Comment: I think even if you (confusingly, imho) restrict your question to contexts describing written text, the question is effectively "Too Broad". And even if not that, it's predominantly a matter of different people's opinions. A *lengthy* text, for example, could be either approvingly or disparagingly referenced as such.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking exactly. Google definitions in English come from the Oxford Dictionary, you can trust them. And nostalgia is one of the feelings that may be represented in "sentimental", so the relation is not so gratuitous. Nostalgic is "included" in sentimental. They are synonyms depending on the exact context. Notice that sentimental has two different meanings https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sentimental

Comment: nostalgia can either be a happy or sad feeling. how is it related to sentimental?

Comment: According to Cambridge Dictionary: A sentimental person is strongly influenced by emotional feelings, especially about happy memories of past events or relationships. Nostalgia:  a feeling of pleasure and also slight sadness when you think about things that happened in the past. Feelings. Past. I can see a relation. The Oxford Dictionary define sentimental as having or arousing feelings of tenderness, sadness, or nostalgia, typically in an exaggerated and self-indulgent way. Feelings, again. Nostalgia explicitly named.

Comment: Also notice that nostalgia may be a mixed feeling both happy and sad at the same time. It's not an exclusive or.

Comment: I think picking out a pile of quasi-synonyms and quasi-antonyms is a hard row to hoe and confusing to say the least. I could have said: brief, short, terse. [replies]. Likewise: detailed, picayune, verbose (answers). So, it can get very complicated. Can you please use capitals when using the pronoun I in English? Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @RubioRic - Google definitions are reliable. The key is that most words have many nuances, so it's hard to define a word completely with one short definition. I like using Wordnik, which will list several definitions from three or four dictionaries, thereby giving a more complete sense of everything a word might mean. You might try looking at Wordnik for [sentimental](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sentimental) and [nostalgia](https://www.wordnik.com/words/nostalgia) to see why Google lists them as synonyms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your definitions are more or less correct.  The only thing I would add is that the difference between *concise* and *succinct* is subtle.  For example you could say:

> A **concise** dictionary of the English language

but not usually

> A **succinct** dictionary of the English language

Both *concise* and *succinct* can mean "short and to the point", but *concise* mostly implies "of reduced size or length".  Otherwise, both can be used in the same contexts.  Also note that neither *requires* that the information be useful or meaningful.  For example:

> The president's speech was **concise/succinct**, but didn't really say anything of substance.

As for the others: yes, *detailed* means "having lots of detail", *thorough* means, "complete", and *lengthy* means "of significant length".

Comment: I didn't say it has anything to do with usefulness. by omiting the unnecessary details I meant continued repetition of same thing and some other misc. stuff. and obviously by doing so the text becomes compact, Concise.

Comment: @user82287  as I said, your definitions are pretty much correct.  I was just adding some additional detail.